# How to parse such text structure into JSON with regexp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, json, parsing

I have a text with structure like this:

```
#object_name object_id
 action_name param1 ... paramN
 module
  action_name_1 param1 ... paramK
  action_name_N param1 ... paramM
 module_end
 some_other_action_name param1 ... paramJ
#some_other_object object_id
 action...
```

So I have objects that start with `#`, `actions` that can take `0` to `N` arguments and `modules` that can have `actions` inside of tham. Each start with new line. Is it possible to create regExp (one or array in loop) that would parse such text structure into JSON object and how to do such thing?

Answer (score 0):

No, and not that a RegExp could parse it. However, your actions or modules (whichever is a function); are not serializable/deserializable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to break the lines into tokens, but you cannot use regular expressions to parse nested structures.  I would just loop through the lines, using split(/\s+/) to break each line into words.